# List Formatting in Tkinter Text Box

Tags: python, text, formatting, tkinter, string-formatting

I was just wondering if there was a way to get each of the elements in a list to display on separate lines, or with a line in between them in a text box in TKinter.  What I have right now is simple code which draws from another file but I am not sure about how to go about this.

My code is this:

```
gui = compare.GCCCOMPARE.compare(mygcccompare)

root = Tk()
text = Text(root)
text.insert(INSERT,  gui)
text.pack() 
root.mainloop()
```

Where `gui` is the list.

What I get in the Text Box is this:

```
["Parameter Change between files 0 and 1 :  {'LPSUM': [(233, 42), '(253, 196)']}", "Parameter Change between files 1 and 2 :  {'LPSUM': [(253, 196), '(15, 194)']}", "Parameter Change between files 2 and 3 :  {'LPSUM': [(15, 194), '(229, 92)'],}"]
```

But what I want is:

```
["Parameter Change between files 0 and 1 :  {'LPSUM': [(233, 42), '(253, 196)']}", 

"Parameter Change between files 1 and 2 :  {'LPSUM': [(253, 196), '(15, 194)']}", 

"Parameter Change between files 2 and 3 :  {'LPSUM': [(15, 194), '(229, 92)']}"]
```

Comment: Try inserting newlines in your list representation.

Comment: That just makes the list show in the text as each element and "\n",  I've found another forum on a similar topic though and one of the answers seems to work.  This is the code which I needed ("\n".join(map(str, listname))).  I have not yet looked up what the map function does but I will have to look at it

Comment: That's what I meant by inserting newlines ;)

Comment: ah, well then thank you! I'm just starting to use python so these functions aren't natural to me yet!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
("\n".join(map(str, listname)))
```

This is what I was looking for.  If anyone seems to have a question like this on formatting a list so that each element is on a new line, this code will work for you

Comment: `map(function, sequence)` is equivalent to `(function(item) for item in sequence)`.